# smarter way to re-assign values for a column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

Suppose have a data frame `df` and column `foo` is float. I want to assign `foo` to be 1, if the value of `foo` is more than one. Wondering if any efficient way to implement in R? If there is a one line implementation, it will be great, similar to lambda expression in Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df$foo[df$foo > 1] <- 1
```

Comment: So smart solution, thanks user2280549, vote up and mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

An efficient approach would be to assign in place with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[foo > 1, foo := 1]
```

Comment: Thanks and vote up, I have two R books and searched solution as well, none of them are as elegant as what I can find from here. :)